# int vs NSNumber vs NSInteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a line of code that will work differently depending on the datatypes "day" and "1". I believe it is the following although I will check my source code later.

`day = day + 1;`

Does this make sense? What would the differences be?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`NSInteger` is a type definition that describes an integer - but it is NOT equivalent to `int` on 64-bit platforms.
You can examine the typedef by cmd-clicking on `NSInteger` in Xcode.
`NSInteger` is defined as `int` when building a 32-bit app and as `long` for 64-bit apps.
Most of the time you can replace int with NSInteger, but there are some things to consider when doing so.
[Apple's 64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/ConvertingExistingApp/ConvertingExistingApp.html) has some information about that.

[NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_25) is a class that helps you to store numeric types as object.  It has methods to convert between different types and methods to retrieve a string representation of your numeric value.
If you use a variable `day` of type `NSNumber*` the way you did in your example, you are not modifying the value of `day` but its memory address.

If you are working with time values you also could take a look at [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 13):

**`NSInteger` is a simply an integer, `NSNumber` is an object where as `int` is a primitive data type.**

NSInteger is nothing more than a synonym for a long integer.

> If you need to store a number somewhere, use NSNumber. If you're doing calculations, loops, etc, use NSInteger, NSUInteger or int.

You can wrap an NSInteger into an NSNumber using:

```
NSNumber *NumberToStore = @(21);
```

and get it back using:

```
NSInteger retrievingInteger = [NumberToStore integerValue];
```

Comment: NSNumber if you need to store a number _as an object_. For example in an NSDictionary or an NSArray or an NSSet.

Answer (score 3):

`NSInteger` and `int` are equivalent, `NSNumber` is an object used to store primitive number types (int, long, float, etc.).

The example code you posted will work just fine if `day` is an `NSinteger`, it won't work at all if it's an `NSNumber`.

Comment: NSInteger and int are not equivalent for 64-bit apps. (NSInteger is defined as long for 64-bit apps). The example code posted will also work if day is an instance of NSNumber but the increment will not change the value but the address of the receiver.  This is most likely not what the OP wants.

Comment: For NSObject, the compiler won't allow you to do pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

`1` is a literal and the compiler will make it the appropriate numeric type if that's appropriate.

Note, however, that while `NSInteger` and `int` are to most intents and purposes the same thing, `NSNumber` is an object type. For that case, your code doesn't make sense (and shouldn't compile without warnings).

(Actually, there are some circumstances where it would make a kind of sense, in terms of pointer arithmetic, but that's totally not what you want.)

For the NSNumber case, you'd instead want something like:

```
day = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[day intValue] + 1];
```