# Weird result from JSON to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa, nsdictionary

I have the following code to get a `NSDictionary` from a JSON:

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."]]];
session.dict[@"ticketsAndAdminsList"] = [NSJSONSerialization
                                         JSONObjectWithData: data
                                         options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                         error: &e];
```

Then, somewhere else I have:

```
int activeTickets = session.dict[@"ticketsAndAdminsList"][@"tickets_pending"] ? (int)session.dict[@"ticketsAndAdminsList"][@"tickets_pending"] : 0;
```

If I put a breakpoint right below that line, `activeTickets`'s value is `55`, even if the value in that dictionary is `0`:

[image: Wrong value]

Any idea why?

Thank you!

Comment: I would look at the different between int and NSNumber: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3032028/620197. Also keep in mind NSDictionary stores objects, not primitives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting `session.dict[@"ticketsAndAdminsList"][@"tickets_pending"]` to an `int`, but it is not a `int` type. It would appear to be a `NSNumber`.

You could do something like:

```
int activeTickets = [session.dict[@"ticketsAndAdminsList"][@"tickets_pending"] intValue];
```

Comment: Any idea why the casting to an int does not work? Just curious.

Comment: Because you're dealing with an object (i.e. a pointer to some memory that holds some object). Casting that pointer to an `int` makes no more sense than casting a view controller to an `int`. Objects and fundamental data types are entirely different types of beasts. If you want a fundamental type value, you have to see if that object provides a method to return that for you (such as `intValue` method of `NSNumber`). BTW, you should be very wary about using casts to convert from one type to another. The compiler generally keeps good track of object types, so we should defer to it when possible.